# Problems to consume from kafka created by docker-compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to get the docker compose from [wurstmeister/kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) to work on my mint, however, I'm getting this error when I try to consume some messages from it.

```
WARN [console-consumer-7198_c0d552365e3b-1455224038666-5fc060cd-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([teste,0]) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(teste)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(BrokerEndPoint(1001,127.0.0.1,32774))] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:73)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:75)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:74)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:119)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
    ... 3 more
```

The log generated by zookeeper is :

```
zookeeper_1 | 2016-02-11 21:10:30,268 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x152d21258da000c type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x51 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers
zookeeper_1 | 2016-02-11 21:10:30,483 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x152d21258da000c type:create cxid:0x19 zxid:0x55 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/console-consumer-51477/owners/teste Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/console-consumer-51477/owners/teste
zookeeper_1 | 2016-02-11 21:10:30,485 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x152d21258da000c type:create cxid:0x1a zxid:0x56 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/console-consumer-51477/owners Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/console-consumer-51477/owners
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://wurstmeister.github.io/kafka-docker/), and I was able to create a topic and produce messages to it, the problem occured when I tried to consume. I set my KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME to 127.0.0.1.
Could this be the problem?

Commands that I executed:

```
 $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic topic --partitions 4 --zookeeper $ZK --replication-factor 2

 $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic topic --zookeeper $ZK 

 $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic=topic --broker-list=`broker-list.sh`

 $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic=topic --zookeeper=$ZK
```

Comment: Which OS are you running Docker on? Which command did you use to run Kafka and which one for ZK? Include Kafka version if you first did `docker pull`and then `run` (I mean, if version is not obvious from your `docker run` command).

Comment: I followed the tutorial. `docker-compose up` runs both, Kafka AND Zookeeper.
My OS is Linux Mint, as I said on my original post.

Comment: My guess is that I messed up with the IP configuration... If you find a solution, please post here.